# Topological distinguishibilty of $\infty$ after one point compactification?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be the one point compactification of some locally compact Hausdorff space. Let $\infty \in X$ represent the added point.

Is there always a homomorphism $\phi:X \to X$ with $\phi: \infty \mapsto x \ne \infty$?

In other words: can you always find a homomorphism from $X$ to itself that maps the point $\infty$ to a different point in X?

It seems to me the answer is supposed to be no.

Comment: Rotations of the sphere?

Comment: If $X=\mathbb R^n$, then the compactification is just a sphere, which has no special point.

Comment: The maybe more interesting question is: Can you exhibit some locally compact $X$ such that there is no homeomorphism that moves $\infty$?

Comment: Rotation of the sphere, or simply compactify $[-1,1)$ by adding $\infty:=1$ and take $x\mapsto -x$.

Comment: @Hagen: maybe the compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ by $\{\omega\}$ satisfies the property that it cannot be moved away?

Comment: rephrased the question accordingly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $\{\frac{1}{n}\,|\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and compactify it with $0$. Any homeomorphism takes the open set $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$ to an open set, i.e. not to $\{0\}$, so $\{0\}$ is fixed.

Comment: Or to say it another way, a homeomorphism maps limit points to limit points, and 0 is the unique limit point of the compactification.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the space that is a circle and two of its diameters minus their intersection (the center of the circle). The one point compactification of this space just adds the center of the circle:
$$\Huge{\otimes}$$ but there are no other points with 
$$\Huge{\times}$$
shaped neighborhoods in this space, so every self-homeomorphism of the one point compactification sends the point at infinity to itself.

Comment: This is very cute.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks :)